# How to check if value exists in Firebase Realtime Database (Dart/Flutter)?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

How can I check if a certain value exists in a Firebase Realtime Database?

I am using the following command but it is not working:

```
Future<bool> rootFirebaseIsExists(DatabaseReference databaseReference) async{
  DataSnapshot snapshot = await databaseReference.once();
  if( snapshot == null ){
    print("Item doesn't exist in the db");
  }else{
    print("Item exists in the db");
  }
  return snapshot !=null;
}
print("exists?");
rootFirebaseIsExists(FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("users").child('userid000').child('pushTokens').child("field_to_check"));
```

The problem is that even when the node doesn't exist the the snapshot is not null and then the function returns that the item exists in the db.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[once()](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/Query/once.html) always yields a [DataSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DataSnapshot-class.html) object.  You have to check if that snapshot contains any data by looking at its [value](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DataSnapshot/value.html) property.

```
  if (snapshot.value == null) {
    print("Item doesn't exist in the db");
  } else {
    print("Item exists in the db");
  }
```